# ggeffect() Not Returning all Predictions

Tags: r, glm, marginal-effects

Using the Seatbelts (included in R) data, I want the predictions for the marginal effect of "front". This variable has 170 values. `ggeffect()` is only returning predictions for front at the values 400, 500, 600, ...,1300. How can I return all of the predictions?

```
Seatbelts <- data.frame(Seatbelts)
head(Seatbelts)

Seatbelts <- Seatbelts[complete.cases(Seatbelts), ]

## 75% of the sample size
smp_size <- floor(0.75 * nrow(Seatbelts))

## set the seed to make your partition reproducible
set.seed(123)
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(Seatbelts)), size = smp_size)

train <- Seatbelts[train_ind, ]
test <- Seatbelts[-train_ind, ]

# glm()
m1 <- glm(DriversKilled  ~  front + rear + kms + PetrolPrice + 
              VanKilled + law,
          family=poisson(link = "log"),
          weights = drivers,
          data=train)

ggeffect(m1, terms = c("front"), typical = "average")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, the function `ggeffect` uses the `Effect` function from the `effects` library to get its data for plotting. If you are interested in seeing the actual numbers predicted at various levels of a particular variable it would be best to get them directly, since it is not the job of `ggeffect` to return an arbitrary list of predictions.

We can get a nice data frame of the prediction and confidence interval at any levels you choose by passing them via the `xlevels` parameter.

```r
predictions <- effects::Effect("front", m1, xlevels = list(front = seq(400, 1300, 5)))

df <-  data.frame(front = predictions$x, 
                  fit   = exp(predictions$fit),
                  lower = exp(predictions$lower),
                  upper = exp(predictions$upper))
```

So the top of our data frame looks like this:

```
head(df)
#>   front      fit    lower    upper
#> 1   400 68.16168 67.99573 68.32803
#> 2   405 68.62226 68.45703 68.78788
#> 3   410 69.08595 68.92146 69.25083
#> 4   415 69.55277 69.38904 69.71689
#> 5   420 70.02275 69.85979 70.18609
#> 6   425 70.49590 70.33373 70.65845
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>